# Given f(x,y), x(t,u) and y(t,u), how do I intuitively calculate the second partial derivative with respect to u?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm a bit confused when dealing with higher order derivatives. Suppose we have a function f(x,y) where x(t,u) and y(t,u).

Can someone help me understand how I should think about solving $\frac{\delta^2f}{\delta x^2}$ or $\frac{\delta^2f}{\delta u^2}$?

I've read my litterature but at some point I started getting confused by the indexing, and I feel now that I don't understand it fully anymore.

I'll walk you through my though process.
When doing the second partial derivative of $\frac{\delta^2f}{\delta u^2}$, my first though is to do $\frac{\delta f}{\delta u}(\frac{\delta f}{\delta u})$, where $\frac{\delta f}{\delta u}=\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}+\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}\frac{\delta y}{\delta u}$ which can be written as: $\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}*f_1+\frac{\delta y}{\delta u}*f_2$, correct? And now to get $\frac{\delta^2f}{\delta u^2}$ one would simply need to compute the result of $\frac{\delta f}{\delta u}(\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}*f_1+\frac{\delta y}{\delta u}*f_2)$, correct?

It is here I start to get confused. When reviewing an example from the litterature they seem to do the opposite of an exercise that I later solved, and my head starts to spin because of all the indexing and so on... But this is what I think I should do...
$\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}(\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}*f_{11}+\frac{\delta x}{\delta t}*f_{12})+\frac{\delta y}{\delta u}(\frac{\delta y}{\delta u}*f_{21}+\frac{\delta y}{\delta t}*f_{22})$

And why is becuase when I review the indexing, $f_{11}$ tells me that I should derivate with respect to the function $f$s first variable, $x$, and again with respect to the first variable of $x$ which is $u$, but is my thinking correct?

So my question is, what is $\frac{\delta^2f}{\delta x^2}$ and $\frac{\delta^2f}{\delta u^2}$ and how can I memorize the steps requiered to compute these things in the future?

EDIT:

Can I perhaps use the fact that $\frac{\delta^2 f}{\delta u^2}=(\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}+\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}\frac{\delta y}{\delta u})(\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}+\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}\frac{\delta y}{\delta u})$  and then simply expand with taking the products of the terms?

If I expand upon this I get:
$\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}(\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}+\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}\frac{\delta y}{\delta u})+\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}\frac{\delta y}{\delta u}(\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}+\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}\frac{\delta y}{\delta u})$.

I can evaluate $\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}=f_{11}$ and the others also get evaluated to such terms, which simplifies it to:

$\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}(f_{11}\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}+f_{12}\frac{\delta y}{\delta u})+\frac{\delta y}{\delta u}(f_{21}\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}+f_{22}\frac{\delta y}{\delta u})$

This is however in contradiction with what I guessed before. Furthermore, if this is correct (which I percieve it to be), how do I then now proceed to derivate these terms now? Given that I have formulas for $x(t,u)$ and $y(t,u).$

Comment: I gave it some further thought and I think that I now fully understand it. The last expression in the text is correct. To solve it I simply take the partial derivatives stated, such as $\frac{\delta x}{\delta u}$ for which there is a function representing that. Is my assesment correct?

The reason is that this question was in regards to a seminar question (which I don't want to disclose), but I got the correct answer on that. And if I understood it as stated then it must be correct.

Comment: Everything is confused and wrong because: $f_{uu}\not=f_u^2$, it is $(f_u)_u$.

Comment: I see, so $\frac{\delta^2 f}{\delta u^2}$ is not equal to $\frac{\delta f}{\delta u} \frac{\delta f}{\delta u}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(t,u)=f(x(t,u),y(t,u))$.

Then
$F_u=f_x x_u  + f_y y_u$ by the Chain Rule.

Note that this is a sum of two products, so we use the Sum, Product rules to get
$$
F_{uu}=
(f_x)_u x_u +f_x x_{uu} 
+ (f_y)_u y_u + f_y y_{uu}.
$$
Now use the Chain Rule twice more to get
$$
F_{uu}=
(f_{xx} x_u +f_{xy} y_u ) x_u +f_x x_{uu} 
+ (f_{yx} x_u +f_{yy}y_u   ) y_u + f_y y_{uu}.
$$

Collect the terms and we  have

$$
F_{uu}= f_{xx}x_u^2 +2 f_{xy} x_u y_u + f_{yy} y_u^2 +f_x x_{uu} + f_y y_{uu}.
$$

Comment: In the case of the exercise I've been working on there is no variable remainder left after the first partial derivation with respect to u. All that remains are constants, then I do not need to take the two last terms in your expression, correct?

Then considering that, is my expression correct?

(The style you're using is quite hard to read for me..)

I think I understand the error I made, which is the second step you did. So my problem was that I did not derivate with respect to the products?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand what a variable remainder is. If you are saying that $x$ and $y$ are linear in $u$ then indeed $x_{uu}=y_{uu}=0$. [You seem to be happy with $f_{11}$, what's wrong with $f_{xx}$? The problem with $f_{11}$ in your account, where you confuse $f$ and $F$, is that it's not clear whether by $f_{11}$ you mean $f_{xx}$ or $f_{uu}$.]

Comment: Yes that was what I meant...

Thank you for your explanations , they've been of much help!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$

$$\implies \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial ^2 x}{\partial u^2} + \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial u^2}$$

$$\implies \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} =  \left(\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+ \frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x \partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial ^2 x}{\partial u^2} + \left(\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x \partial y}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+ \frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial y^2}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\right)\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial u^2}$$

Comment: Is this the same expression as the one last one I got? It seems as if you did not expand upon the last partial derivation with respect to u, correct? I use indexing because I find it easier!

Comment: You're missing a whole lot of terms.

Comment: You'd have 4 terms - two sqaure terms and two cross terms - which terms am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the two $f_{xy} x_u y_u$ terms.

Comment: Got it, corrected the mistake - realised I overlooked the chain rule again